# Dynamically Created Div is getting invisible

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a div dynamically by clicking a button and add it to the parent name "option_selection". But the div get 'vanished' (I don't know what else could I say because saying 'invisible' may mean something else!).

Here is my JS code:

```
function addMoreOptions(div){
   var counter_div = document.getElementById("hidden");
   var counter = counter_div.value;
   counter_div.setAttribute("id","not_hidden");
   counter_div.setAttribute("name","not_hidden");
   counter++;
   var addString="";
   addString = addString+"<div style="\"width:" 250px;="" float:="" left;="" \"="">";
   addString = addString+"<p>Choose option type to display :</p></div>";
   addString = addString+"<div style="\"float:" left;\"=""><select id="\"option_type\"" name="\"option_type_";" addstring="addString+counter;"><option value="\"1\"">Single Option (radio button)</option>";
   addString = addString+"<option value="\"2\"">Multiple Option (check boxes)</option>";
   addString = addString+"<option value="\"3\"">Text Entry (text input box)</option>";
   addString = addString+"<option value="\"4\"">Menu(Drop Down)</option></select></div>";
   addString = addString+"<div style="\"float:" none;="" clear:="" both;="" width:="" 0px;\"=""></div>";
   addString = addString+"<div style="\"width:" 250px;="" float:="" left;="" \"="">";
   addString = addString+"<p>Enter option text:</p></div><div style="\"float:" left;\"="">";
   addString = addString+"<input type="\"text\"" id="\"option_text_1\"" name="\"option_text_";" addstring="addString+counter;"><input id="\"hidden\"" type="\"hidden\"" name="\"hidden\"" value="";
   addString = addString+counter;
   addString = addString+""></div><div style="\"float:" none;="" clear:="" both;="" width:="" 0px;\"=""></div>";
   var element = document.createElement("div");
   element.innerHTML= addString;   
   document.getElementById(div).appendChild(element);
   alert(document.getElementById(div).innerHTML);
}
```

here is the HTML Code

```
        <div id="option_selection">
            <div>
                <div style="width: 250px; float: left; "><p>Choose option type to display :</p></div>
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <select id="option_type" name="option_type_1">
                        <option value="1">Single Option (radio button)</option>
                        <option value="2">Multiple Option (check boxes)</option>
                        <option value="3">Text Entry (text input box)</option>
                        <option value="4">Menu(Drop Down)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div style="float: none; clear: both; width: 0px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 250px; float: left; "><p>Enter option text:</p></div>
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <input type="text" id="option_text_1" name="option_text_1">
                    <input id="hidden" name="hidden" type="hidden" value="1">                            
                </div>
                <div style="float: none; clear: both; width: 0px;"></div>
            </div>                    
        </div>                
        <div align="right" style="width: 800px;">
            <button id="add" onclick="addMoreOptions('option_selection')">Add More Option</button>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please add the code on stackoverflow, it prevents link rot.

Comment: Make that relevant code.

Comment: sorry, I could not get what you two have said :(

Comment: you can see the HTML page here http://workspace.webpers.com/blog/problem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `button` has no `type`-attribute. The default type of buttons is `submit` (also see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button#Attributes)).

> **type**
>      The type of the button. Possible values are:
>          - *submit*: The button submits the form data to the server. **This is the default if the attribute is not specified**, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
>          - *reset*: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
>          - *button*: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

Add `type="button"` and on click the form won't be submitted.

```
<button type="button" id="add" onclick="addMoreOptions('option_selection')">Add More Option</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = element;
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementById(div).appendChild(element);
```

Comment: Okay, I have tried that but it did not work. Moreover, I think that is not supposed to work as that tries to add an OBJECT to the HTML code.

Comment: okay I think I got the answer. While I was pressing the add more button the script is actually adding the div but it is also submitting the form (which is pretty weird! I would love to know the reason why the button is submitting the question!!!). Adding a "return false;" after the function call solves the problem.